# Paste Value Only (Case)

Tags: excel, vba

the selected range has formulas, how to paste the range as values only?

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim PasteRng As Range
Select Case LCase(Range("AG14").Value)
  Case "ready to wearmen": Set PasteRng = Sheets("PowerBi").Range("B4:B34")
  Case "ready to wearwomen": Set PasteRng = Sheets("PowerBi").Range("C4:C34")
  Case "shoesmen": Set PasteRng = Sheets("PowerBi").Range("D4:D34")
  Case "shoeswomen": Set PasteRng = Sheets("PowerBi").Range("E4:E34")
End Select
Range("AG16:AG46").Copy PasteRng
       
End Sub
```

I tried to write .Value or .PasteSpecial but I am not sure where to add it

Comment: use `Range("AG16:AG46").Copy: PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` or `PasteRng.Value = [AG16:AG46].Value`

Comment: Is this code located in the same workbook as worksheet `PowerBi`? Is the `AG` column located in worksheet `PowerBi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a separate method than the regular paste. PasteSpecial. See below.

```
Sub Macro4()
' Macro4 Macro
    Dim PasteRng As Range
    Select Case LCase(Range("AG14").Value)
      Case "ready to wearmen": Set PasteRng = Sheets("PowerBi").Range("B4:B34")
      Case "ready to wearwomen": Set PasteRng = Sheets("PowerBi").Range("C4:C34")
    End Select

    Range("AG16:AG46").Copy
    PasteRng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) '<<----- add here
    

End Sub
```